# Unable to install cobetura plugin in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, cobertura, ecobertura

I'm trying to install Cobertura plugin (http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update/) on Helios version of my eclipse but getting this exception "org.eclipse.equinox.p2.core.ProvisionException", It says unable to read repository at http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update/

I'm not on proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

Seems it had stopped development. 
I can't install it in Eclipse 3.5 or 4.3 too.

You can use [EclEmma](http://www.eclemma.org/), it's easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse Helios version is 3.6.x and [eCobertura Web site](http://ecobertura.johoop.de/) states that eclipse update site works for Eclipse 3.5+. I can confirm it really is working for Eclipse Helios. If you can download [update site meta information](http://ecobertura.johoop.de/update/content.jar) through browser, but eclipse still cannot see it, it could be a proxy problem or something else that prevents eclipse to access content of update site.